# git how to merge branches with conflict with master

Tags: git

I have a problem here:  I have a branch feature in development and it posts a decent number of conflicts with master branch.  I would like to make a pull request  in the future to merge it with master.

Right now, I would hope to resolve some conflicts with master (not planning to merge yet). Will there be a recommended way for me to do that?  I am thinking about creating a new branch with the up-to-date master and either cherry-pick or pull the  feature branch and resolve conflict accordingly.  Is that the right way? Also, in the future after more master pushes, should I redo the same process to resolve conflict? Thank you!

Comment: You may either rebase feature on master, or merge master into feature.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you, will it distort the work tree? Do you mean checkout a master branch (or a new branch same as master) then do rebase feature? Ideally I would hope the tree will just be additional commits on top of current master?

Comment: have you check [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git), suggested many ways to achieve and also http://weblog.masukomi.org/2008/07/12/handling-and-avoiding-conflicts-in-git/

Answer (score 0):

> Do you mean checkout a master branch (or a new branch same as master) then do rebase feature?

No:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

> Ideally I would hope the tree will just be additional commits on top of current master?

Exactly: it rewrites the `feature` branch on top of `master`, which changes the history of `feature`. So make sure you warn your colleagues working on that same branch.
And, as seen here, do activate [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) to avoid having to resolve the same conflicts every time you are rebasing that branch on `master`.